# calling wcf service without waiting for response from console application

Tags: wcf, console-application

I presume , such a mode should exist. Just triggering WCF service and exiting. Something else will check a log ( database/file ) produced by WCF service. My understanding it is different to asynchronous call where calling application allows to do something else, but still runs some code on completion event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your optimal solution would be an asynchronous one-way call.

The *one-way* part of it says that you want to call the method, but don't expect any result back. See [What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx) for more details on that part.

The *asynchronous* part of it makes sure your call returns right away - not waiting for the service-side to pick up your message.

So basically you need:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
   public void OneWayCall()
}
```

and then call this in an asynchronous matter.